# How to Set UIScrollView 'main' content to be height of screen - with 'secondary' content 'below the fold'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I've been banging my head against the wall with this one for a while now.

I have a single view application that has it's main content displayed in a scroll view - initially so that pull to refresh could be implemented easily. This is working and implemented using storyboards and AutoLayout constraints.

I have got a new feature that I would like to implement, however I don't want it to always be visible, I want it to be displayed underneath the 'main' content in the scroll view. This way, the user must scroll the main view in order to see the extra content. I've made up a small diagram that will hopefully convey this better than words:

[image: UIScrollView Diagram]

I have tried simply placing the secondary content underneath the last block of main content with a vertical constraint - this lets you scroll to it, but the Scroll View  snaps back to it's original position once you let go.

Any tips on how to solve this are very welcome, thank you!

Edit:

Here is a simplified hierarchy of what I have tried:

- UIScrollView

  - Scrolling Content

    - Main Content View

      - Content...
    - Secondary Content View

      - Content...

I think the difficulty is arising because I want the Main Content View to be the full height of the screen.

Comment: When you drag the red view up, it reveals the green view, but does the green view move upward as well or is it just revealed when the red view is moved up? And when you say _snaps back_, does the red view position itself again on the entire screen?

Comment: Why not to put that secondary content inside the scrollview

Comment: I should confirm: the secondary content is within the scrollview. I have updated the question with a simplified hierarchy of what I'm doing.

Comment: @TreeTrum Please see my answer below, and let me know if it addresses your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to position your views inside your scrollview, and set the `contentSize` of the scrollView.

**View Controller**

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    /* Set the contentSize of the scrollview */
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height*2)

    /* Adding two views, red, green at different locations inside the scrollview */
    let red = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    red.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    let green = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height, width: width, height: height))
    green.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    /* Adding the views in the scrollview */
    self.scrollView.addSubview(red)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(green)

}
```

**Demo**

[image: Example]

Comment: Is there any way of doing this using storyboards and constraints? My app is already fully implemented using storyboard - no layout is done programatically at the moment.

Comment: @TreeTrum You can add the views from storyboard instead of programmatically making them. But for fine control and placement, linking these views from your storyboard to your view controller and programmatically setting their frames would be the way to go.

Comment: Ok, I think I finally got something working. I used your advice and added my 'main content' and my 'secondary content' to my ViewController as IBOutlets, then I was able to set the scrollviews content height to be the total of the main and secondary contents. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Separate the content of the main view to 2 parts up part which is a view that has the height of the screen and the bottom part that has height of contents in secondary part

```
ScrollView
      contentView -> equal width of screen
          topView -> equal height of screen
          secondaryView -> equal height of it's subview
```